# How to solve percentage difference problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, percentages

I am trying to figure out how to solve percentage difference problem?

Adam, Tom and Carl are selling lemonade and customers are giving likes. Adams received 40% more likes
than Carl. Tom got 20% fewer likes than Carl. By what percentage did Adam get more likes
than Tom?

I am thinking 
Adam likes are at 140%, Tom likes are at 80%, so Adam got 140 - 80 = 60% more likes than Tom.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say, Adam, Tom and Carl has $a, t$ and $c$ amount of likes.

Then we can make some equations from the question.

$$a=1.4c$$

$$t=0.8c$$

Then to find percentage that Adam got more than Tom,

\begin{align}
\frac{a}{t}&=\frac{1.4c}{0.8c} \\
&=1.75
\end{align}

So the answer is $75\%$.

Comment: Thank you so much... this is great.

Comment: do you mean 1.4c/08.c ? I see you posted 1.4t/0.8c

Comment: @Vinod Yes, thank you, I've changed it.

Comment: @Laduros, how did you figure out you have to divide instead of subtraction. I just started learning algebra

Answer (score 1):

markup and margin shows for tom to be at the same number of likes as Carl, he needed ${1\over 1-0.2}-1 = 0.25=25\%$ more, which then needs 40% more of that value to get to Adam. This means he needs $$(1+0.25)\cdot (1+0.4)= 1+0.25+0.4+0.1=1.75$$ or 75% more than what he has.

Comment: Now I got it. Your explanation helped me think thru it. Lets say Carl has 100 likes. So Tom has 20% less likes than Carl, which is nothing but 100 - 100*0.2 = 100 - 20 = 80.
Adam has 40% more likes than Carl, which means 100 + 100*0.4 = 140.
So for Tom 25% of 80 is nothing but 80*0.25 = 20. To go from 80 to 140, he needs 60 more likes. Which is nothing but 20*3, which translates to 25% * 3, so it becomes 75%.